# WebdriverIO - Junit reporter - .xml file is not getting generated

Tags: xml, junit, webdriver-io

Node version - 14.21.3
NPM versiob - 6.14.18

I have WebdriverIO based UI automation framework. Following are the dev dependencies in package.json file:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.4.2",
    "@wdio/allure-reporter": "^7.29.1",
    "@wdio/cli": "^7.30.0",
    "@wdio/dot-reporter": "^7.19.7",
    "@wdio/junit-reporter": "^7.31.1",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^7.16.13",
    "@wdio/mocha-framework": "^7.16.13",
    "@wdio/selenium-standalone-service": "^7.31.1",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^7.31.1",
    "allure-commandline": "^2.23.0",
    "chai": "^4.3.7",
    "chromedriver": "^109.0.0",
    "totp-generator": "0.0.13",
    "wdio-allure-reporter": "^0.8.3",
    "wdio-chromedriver-service": "^7.3.2",
    "wdio-image-comparison-service": "^3.1.1",
    "wdio-junit-reporter": "^0.4.4",
    "wdio-video-reporter": "^3.5.0"
  }
```

Following is the code in my wdio.config.js:

```
const path = require("path");
const { join } = require("path");
exports.config = {
  reporters: ['spec',
  ['dot',
      ['junit', {
          outputDir: './',
          outputFileFormat: function(options) { // optional
              return `results-file.xml`
          }
      }]
    ] 
  ],
  
  baseUrl: process.env,
  suites: {
    REGRESSION: [
      [
        "./test/specs/RegressionTests/sometest.js",
      ],
    ],
    
  },

  specs: ["./test/specs/**/*.js"],
  // Patterns to exclude.
  exclude: [
    // 'path/to/excluded/files'
  ],
  maxInstances: 10,
  capabilities: [
    {
      // maxInstances can get overwritten per capability. So if you have an in-house Selenium
      // grid with only 5 firefox instances available you can make sure that not more than
      // 5 instances get started at a time.
      maxInstances: 5,
      //
      browserName: "chrome",
      "goog:chromeOptions": {
        args: [
          "--lang=en-US",
          "--no-sandbox",
          "--incognito",
          '--headless',
          "--autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required", // https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/
          //'user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.51 Safari/537.36',
          "--log-level=3", // Disable unusual logging in windows run
          "--disable-gpu",
          "--start-maximized",
          "--disable-popup-blocking",
          "--profile-directory=Default",
          "--disable-infobars",
          "--ignore-certificate-errors",
          "--disable-plugins-discovery",
          "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
          "--no-service-autorun",
          "--no-default-browser-check",
          "--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled",
          "--disable-infobars",
          "--disable-browser-side-navigation",
          "--disable-translate",
          "--disable-extensions",
          "--allow-insecure-localhost",
          "--window-size=1920,1080", // This is browser size
          "--disable-features=VizDisplayCompositor",
          "--disable-prompt-on-repost",
          "--new-window",
          //"--headless",
        ],
      },
      acceptInsecureCerts: true,
      // If outputDir is provided WebdriverIO can capture driver session logs
      // it is possible to configure which logTypes to include/exclude.
      // excludeDriverLogs: ['*'], // pass '*' to exclude all driver session logs
      // excludeDriverLogs: ['bugreport', 'server'],
    },
  ],
  logLevel: "silent",
  logLevels: {
    webdriver: "info",
    "@wdio/appium-service": "info",
  },
  bail: 0,
  baseUrl: "http://localhost",
  waitforTimeout: 90000,
  connectionRetryTimeout: 120000,
  connectionRetryCount: 3,
  services: [
    [
      [
        "chromedriver",
        {
          logFileName: "wdio-chromedriver.log", // default
          outputDir: "driver-logs", // overwrites the config.outputDir
          args: ["--silent"],
          chromedriverCustomPath:
            "C:\\Users\\priya.Ingole\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32 (1)",
        },
      ],
    ],

    [
      [
        "image-comparison",
        // The options
        {
          actualFolder: path.join(process.cwd()),
          baselineFolder: join(process.cwd(), "./basline"),
          formatImageName: "{tag}",
          screenshotPath: join(process.cwd(), "./screenshots"),
          savePerInstance: false,
          autoSaveBaseline: true,
          blockOutStatusBar: true,
          blockOutToolBar: true,
          clearRuntimeFolder: true,
          disableCSSAnimation: true,
          ignoreAlpha: true,
          ignoreAntialiasing: true,
        },
      ],
    ],
  ],

  framework: "mocha",
  reporters: ["spec"],

  mochaOpts: {
    ui: "bdd",
    timeout: 1200000,
  },
  afterTest: function (
    test,
    context,
    { error, result, duration, passed, retries }
  ) {},

};
```

I also installed junit-reporter using command:
npm install @wdio/junit-reporter --save-dev

The test executes successfully but the report-file.xml is not getting generated. What could be the issue?

Comment: Where are you calling the export method?

Comment: I am new to WebdriverIO and node. I am not calling this anywhere. What I want is when I run the command npm run regression it should execute the tests and create the junit xml file. What do I have to do for it?

Comment: See following : http://beta.webdriver.io/docs/junit-reporter.html

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by adding follwing code at the end of wdio.conf.js file.

```
reporters: ['spec',
    'dot',
    ['junit', {
        outputDir: './',            
        outputFileFormat: function(options) { // optional
            return `results-file.xml`
        }
    }]
  ],
```